# Convert R data table column from JSON to data table

Tags: json, r, data.table

I have a column that contains JSON data as in the following example,

```
library(data.table)
test <- data.table(a = list(1,2,3), 
           info = list("{'duration': '10', 'country': 'US'}", 
                       "{'duration': '20', 'country': 'US'}",
                       "{'duration': '30', 'country': 'GB', 'width': '20'}"))
```

I want to convert the last column to equivalent R storage, which would look similar to,

```
res <- data.table(a = list(1, 2, 3),
                  duration = list(10, 20, 30),
                  country = list('US', 'US', 'GB'),
                  width = list(NA, NA, 20))
```

Since I have 500K rows with different contents I would look for a quick way to do this.

Comment: Ok, feel free to edit if you know how to correct it in some way that doesn't break the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A variation without the need to separate out the JSON string

```
library(data.table)
library(jsonlite)

test[, info := gsub("'", "\"", info)]
test[, rbindlist(lapply(info, fromJSON), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)]

#    duration country width
# 1:       10      US    NA
# 2:       20      US    NA
# 3:       30      GB    20
```

Comment: nice data table solution! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Parse the JSON first, then build the data.frame (or data.table):

```
json_string <- paste(c("[{'duration': '10', 'country': 'US'}", 
    "{'duration': '20', 'country': 'US'}",
  "{'duration': '30', 'country': 'GB'}",
  "{'width': '20'}]"), collapse=", ")

# JSON standard requires double quotes
json_string <- gsub("'", "\"", json_string)

library("jsonlite")
fromJSON(json_string)

#  duration country width
# 1       10      US  <NA>
# 2       20      US  <NA>
# 3       30      GB  <NA>
# 4     <NA>    <NA>    20
```

This isn't exactly what you asked for as your JSON doesn't associate 'width' with the previous record, you might need to do some manipulation first:

```
json_string <- paste(c("[{'duration': '10', 'country': 'US'}", 
    "{'duration': '20', 'country': 'US'}",
  "{'duration': '30', 'country': 'GB', 'width': '20'}]"), 
  collapse=", ")

json_string <- gsub("'", "\"", json_string)
df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(json_string)
data.table::as.data.table(df)

#    duration country width
# 1:       10      US    NA
# 2:       20      US    NA
# 3:       30      GB    20
```

Comment: consider using `setDT(df)` in place of `data.table::as.data.table(df)`